# Vibe force close. Vibrate

Tags: java, android, forceclose, vibration

I have a line of code that calls the **Vibrator service**.

```
        if (vibe){
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(2000);
                        run();
                    } else {
                        run();
                    }
```

My app is force closing on that. Is it cause the emulator doesn't have a vibrator? Or did i do it wrong?

Comment: What do the error messages say the problem is? What does the documentation say about testing features not supported by the emulator?

Comment: I just ran it on my device, still force closing cause the vibe was taking too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Please keep in mind that the vibrator alarm does not work on the Android emulator.

Comment: Ran it on my device, still force closes

Comment: You must have some errors in your code then. Please attach your code.

Comment: My force close was caused by `java.lang.security.exception: Requires Vibrate Permission`. I feel this is an entirely different question. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523265/vibrator-permission-force-close)

Comment: @Binghammer Yes, in that case it is a different question, and the answer is declare the permission in the manifest.