# Vibrator permission force close

Tags: java, android, permissions, vibration

I have this line of code calling 2 seconds from the `vibrator_service`;

```
 Vibrator v = (Vibrator)
                        getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(2000);
```

and this in my manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" ></permission>
```

But I am still getting a force close `java.lang.security.exception: Requires Vibrate Permission`.  Have I declared the permission wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `uses-permission` tag in the manifest file (as a child of the `manifest` element, same as the `permission` tag):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

As far as I know, the `permission` tag is only used to add additional text/graphic information to the permissions request when downloading the app, or to add new permissions to provide additional information to your users. I usually use both to be safe.